# Create a vector from a .txt data file in R

Tags: r, vector, creation

It's my first time here on stackoverflow so be indulgent with me in the beginning, I'm not fully aware of all the rules here. :)
My first topic would concern vector creation from a .txt data file in R.

I have this kind of data:

```
Piece   Mes.1   Mes.2   Mes.3   Mes.1.2 Mes.2.2 Mes.3.2

1   50  49  50  50  48  51

2   52  52  51  51  51  51

3   53  50  50  54  52  51

4   49  51  50  48  50  51
```

and I would like to create a vector directly from the .txt file without having to rewrite each number.
The vector that I would like to create would include all the data line by line:

```
x<-c(50,49,50,50,48,51,52,52,51,51,51,51,53,50,50,54,52,51,49,51,50,
     48,50,51,48,49,48,48,49,48,52,50,50,52,50,50,51,51,51,51,50,50,
     52,50,49,53,48,50,50,51,50,51,48,49,47,46,49,46,47,48)
```

The name of my data file in R is "data1" and have tried this below but it doesn't work:

```
y<-c(data1[1,2:7],data1[2,2:7],data1[3,2:7]
```

and so on until 10, but it doesn't work.

You guys would be a great help if someone can provide a solution :)
Thanks !

Comment: It doesn't work how? How did you get the text file into a data frame/matrix/whatever `data1` is?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the code below

```
df <- read.table(file = "data.txt", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
x <- as.vector(t(as.matrix(df[-1])))
```

such that

```
> x
 [1] 50 49 50 50 48 51 52 52 51 51 51 51 53 50 50 54 52 51 49 51 50 48 50
[24] 51
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Piece = 1:4, Mes.1 = c(50L, 52L, 53L, 49L), Mes.2 = c(49L, 
52L, 50L, 51L), Mes.3 = c(50L, 51L, 50L, 50L), Mes.1.2 = c(50L, 
51L, 54L, 48L), Mes.2.2 = c(48L, 51L, 52L, 50L), Mes.3.2 = c(51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `scan` is the best way of doing it, it reads line by line and returns vectors, there is no need to convert to matrix, transpose and unlist.

Read in the first line to know how many columns are there in the table. Then read in the data directly into a vector and remove the extra, first column, elements.

```
n <- length(scan(file = "data.txt", nlines = 1L, what = character()))
y <- scan(file = "data.txt", skip = 1L)
y <- y[-seq(1, length(y), by = n)]
y
```

Now compare to the first 24 elements of the posted expected result.

```
identical(x[1:24], y)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 2 line solution to your problem

```
data1<-read.delim('data1.txt',header=TRUE,sep = " ")

your_dear_vector<-as.vector(unlist(t(as.matrix(data1[,-1]))))
```

Enjoy and keep posting!